# Merge two lists based on deltas

Tags: algorithm

I think it's similar to offline data synchronization, but it doesn't have to be nearly as extreme as that.

So I'm looking for a way to merge two, likely similar, sets of data that are aware of their version (so where they split) , aware of the set of CRUD actions that got them to their most recent versions. The difference being the child set is probably off by one or many actions per one version while the authority set has multiple versions with around one delta per version.

Say you have two lists. Lists A and List B. You have 3 versions. Version ab, version abcde, and version abk.

In version ab it is 1, 2, 3.

List A is version abcde.

- In version abc it appended item 4.
- In version abcd it moved item 1 to last place.
- In version abcde it deleted item 3.
- It looks like 2, 4, 1 in the latest version.

List B is version abk.

- In version abk it appended item 4k.
- It looks like 1, 2, 3, 4k in the latest version.

The goal is to synchronize List B with the authority, A, by sending what it did in version abk - and getting back a response for the deltas it needs to get from version abk to abcdef. Where abcdef will be list A merged with list B.

Given the information I have above, how might the logic look for merging two lists using deltas based on their versions look like? Is there additional information needed for efficiently doing a merge between deltas? Or maybe what is a good direction on this? I'm hoping to synchronize the two to a new version by having one send the deltas to another and getting deltas back that bring the old list up to speed.

Comment: How do you plan to handle conflicts?  Suppose that you start with `1, 2, 3` then A moves item 1 to last place and B moves item 2 to last place, do you wish to wind up with `3, 1, 2` or `3, 2, 1`?

Comment: I'd personally start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation and see how well that works.